# Subseting with second muscle group

Tags: weightlifting, strength, workout, strength-training

Just a question about subsetting: 
My week is broken up to two muscle groups on 4 days a week. Let's say I'm doing back and Bis on the same day; would it be bad if I subset my back exercises with my bicep exercises to cut down on time? Or is that going to effect my gains or cause injury? I was just thinking that I could utilize my rest time by using it to hit the exercises I need to do for the other muscle group.

For clarification let's say it back/bi day. I do 4 back exercises (1 is a set of 4 and the rest are sets of 3) and 4 bicep exercises (1 is a set of 4 and the rest are sets of 3)
I'll do back exercise 1 set 1 and immediately follow it with bicep exercise 1 set 1 and then have a short rest before doing set 2 of both.

Comment: The order of exercises will not typically affect your ability to make gains, or, incur injuries.  Of course, that all changes if you rush through each set with poor form.